# Legend not getting appended into div but printing outside the div

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing Donut Chart</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #first {
      /*    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;*/
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21;
      position: absolute;
    }
    #chart {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #chart legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    #first legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    .slice path {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .textTop {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
      fill: #2c3218;
    }
    .textBottom {
      fill: #444;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <svg id="chart" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <div id="first">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var w = document.getElementById('first').clientWidth;
           // alert(w);
          var h = document.getElementById('first').clientHeight;
           // alert(h);
          var r = Math.min(w, h) / 2 - 50;
           // alert(r);
          var inner = 70;
          var color = d3.scale.category10();

          var data = [
            ["192.168.12.1", 20],
            ["76.09.45.34", 40],
            ["34.91.23.76", 80],
            ["192.168.19.32", 16],
            ["192.168.10.89", 50],
            ["192.178.34.07", 18],
            ["192.168.12.98", 30]
          ];

          var data = data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              IP: d[0],
              count: d[1]
            };
          });

          var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
            return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
          });

          var vis = d3.select("#first")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .data([data])
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + r * 1.5 + "," + r * 1.5 + ")");

          var textTop = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textTop")
            .text("TOTAL")
            .attr("y", -10),

            textBottom = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textBottom")
            .text(total)
            .attr("y", 10);

          var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner)
            .outerRadius(r);

          var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner + 0)
            .outerRadius(r + 1);

          var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .startAngle(1.1 * Math.PI)
            .endAngle(3.1 * Math.PI)
            .value(function(d) {
              return d.count;
            });

          var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("d", arcOver)
                .style('opacity', 0.5)

              textTop.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.IP)
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.count)
                .attr("y", 10);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style('opacity', 1);

              textTop.text("TOTAL")
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(total);
            });

          arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .transition()
            .ease("exp")
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

          function tweenPie(b) {
            var i = d3.interpolate({
              startAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI,
              endAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI
            }, b);
            return function(t) {
              return arc(i(t));
            };
          }

          var legend = d3.select("#first")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("x", w)
            .attr("y", h)
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", w / 2)
            .attr("height", h)
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
            });

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.IP;
            });
        </script>
      </div>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = $("#chart"),
      aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
      container = chart.parent();
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      var targetWidth = container.width();
      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
      chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
    }).trigger("resize");
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried a lot but I am unable to display the donut and the legends properly inside the `div` `#first`. I have tried to change a lot of things but nothing works for. Is this impossible what I am trying to do using d3 or there is any specific error that I am doing. Also the div and chart are not getting responsive also. I am confused. Please anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using separate SVGs for for legend and pichart. I append legend into previously used SVG and transform for its position.

Below code snippet may help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing Donut Chart</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #first {
      /*    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;*/
      height: 95% !important;
      width: 95% !important;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
    }
    #chart {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #chart legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    #first legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    .slice path {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .textTop {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
      fill: #2c3218;
    }
    .textBottom {
      fill: #444;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <svg id="chart" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <div id="first">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var w = document.getElementById('first').clientWidth;
           // alert(w);
          var h = document.getElementById('first').clientHeight;
           // alert(h);
          var r = Math.min(w, h) / 2 - 50;
           // alert(r);
          var inner = 70;
          var color = d3.scale.category10();

          var data = [
            ["192.168.12.1", 20],
            ["76.09.45.34", 40],
            ["34.91.23.76", 80],
            ["192.168.19.32", 16],
            ["192.168.10.89", 50],
            ["192.178.34.07", 18],
            ["192.168.12.98", 30]
          ];

          var data = data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              IP: d[0],
              count: d[1]
            };
          });

          var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
            return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
          });

          var vis = d3.select("#first")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .data([data])
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + r * 1.5 + "," + r * 1.5 + ")");

          var textTop = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textTop")
            .text("TOTAL")
            .attr("y", -10),

            textBottom = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textBottom")
            .text(total)
            .attr("y", 10);

          var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner)
            .outerRadius(r);

          var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner + 0)
            .outerRadius(r + 1);

          var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .startAngle(1.1 * Math.PI)
            .endAngle(3.1 * Math.PI)
            .value(function(d) {
              return d.count;
            });

          var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("d", arcOver)
                .style('opacity', 0.5)

              textTop.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.IP)
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.count)
                .attr("y", 10);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style('opacity', 1);

              textTop.text("TOTAL")
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(total);
            });

          arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .transition()
            .ease("exp")
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

          function tweenPie(b) {
            var i = d3.interpolate({
              startAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI,
              endAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI
            }, b);
            return function(t) {
              return arc(i(t));
            };
          }

          var legend = vis.append("g")
            /*.attr("id", "first")
            .append("g")*/
            .attr("transform", "translate("+w / 3+", -"+ h/4 +")")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", w / 2)
            .attr("height", h)
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
            });

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.IP;
            });
        </script>
      </div>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = $("#chart"),
      aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
      container = chart.parent();
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      var targetWidth = container.width();
      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
      chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
    }).trigger("resize");
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dipendra for your suggestion. I tried your codes and its working fine as per my need. I understood my mistake. But as of now only my div border box is getting responsive but not the pie chart and legend. If I decrease the screen size the div size is responding but the contents inside div. What is wrong in my jquery part... I don't know what to change to make my chart and legend responsive. Can you please suggest me

Comment: @rachita welcome. it seems like the problem you were in, is solved. For others who are looking for the same issue can get the help once you accept this answer. 
Now, for this point you should post new question for the improved functionality.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much for your suggestions